# How do I make my Blu-ray / DVD / HD-DVD drive multi-region?

Tags: dvd, blu-ray, regional-settings

I have a combined DVD / HD-DVD / Blu-ray drive on my machine (yeah, I'm very much the big man) which is all great and everything.

However, I've got quite a few region 1 DVDs that it won't play. I know I can switch my drive's region but this is limited to 5 times only.

Is there a way I can make the drive permanently multi-region or lift this limit, the same way you can with most DVD players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't live in the 'land of the free' you can also install DVD43 which decrypts DVDs in the background and shows them to the player as region free.

Comment: Remember that when you play a DVD that you have bought legally on a computer you own - you are talking Learjets from the mouths of poor starving artists.

Comment: LOL @mgb. Upvoted. s/talking/taking/

Answer (score 5):

[AnyDVD HD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvdhd.html) can strip the region codes from (most?) HD and Blu-Ray disks.  I do not believe either DVD43 or VLC will do that, I think they only work on DVDs.

Answer (score 3):

Most drives will not let you do this - but you should be able to use a program like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org) to get around the regions in software.